# How to host Blazon in Razor Pages application

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

The "standard" Blazor WASM application is hosted inside a static HTML page; e.g., `index.html`. Due to certain requirements, I want to host Blazor inside a Razor pages application.

What I did is starting from a "standard" Blazor WASM application, removed the static files, because I do not need them, moved the content of `index.html` to the `Wasm.cshtml`, and change `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` to `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Wasm");`.

Everything seemed to be working as expected; I can run the application and navigate to the different pages I have in Blazor.

However, things fall apart when I try to access a page using its URL; e.g., `http://mysite/counter`, where `/counter` is a page in Blazor, and I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

/Wasm
/Wasm
```

Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

P.S.:

- I looked at some answer here, but all that I found is people talking about Blazor Server.
- I am using .NET 3.1 and Blazor 3.2.
- I want to use my Razor Pages application to host/serve Blazor WASM not mixing them in a single project. They as still 2 different projects.
- I am totally aware that Blazor WASM and Razor Pages are unrelated technologies. I am not trying to integrate them. I am only trying to server Blazor WASM files from a dynamic page. If it makes you think better about what I am trying to achieve, think about Razor Pages as any server-side technology; PHP, Node, or whatever, then apply this to the routing issue that I am trying to resolve.

Comment: How would this even work?  Which platform (Razor Pages or Blazor) would handle routing?

Comment: Isn't that what `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/index")` is supposed to take care of? From the docs: [it] is intended to handle cases where URL path of the request does not contain a file name, and no other endpoint has matched. This is convenient for routing requests for dynamic content to a SPA framework, while also allowing requests for non-existent files to result in an HTTP 404.

Comment: I can understand this if it is the only things that is going on here. But I get the same error even when I change the route of Blazor `Index.razor` page. Anyway, it looks like I'm missing something here, which is what I am asking about.

Comment: it is still not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here;  Razor and Blazor aren't competing frameworks, they are different implementations of the same technology.  Why would you put one dynamic framework inside a second dynamic framework?

Comment: In short, I have an existing Razor Pages application and I want to add Blazor to it, because of certain requirements that I want to implement them in SPA-like page. If they are not competing, what is the problem of having them live together? I can host a JavaScript framework inside a Razor Pages application, can't I? Razor will handle the routing and when it reaches a Blazor page, Blazor will take it from there, because none of the pages will reach the server to have conflict in routing. My issue is with replacing `index.html`.

Comment: "none of the pages will reach the server to have conflict in routing"  how exactly is that?  `http://mysite/counter` will always be a server request.

Comment: the route would have to be something like `http://razorsite/blazorpage/blazorroute` (theoretically).

Comment: I was talking about when I click things inside Blazor. For `http://mysite/counter`, I want to replace the fallback to work, because I do not have a server-side `/counter` page; i.e., `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/index")` that I am unable to make it work.

Comment: What is `/blazorpage` in your example? It is `/Index` in my example, or you can think about it as `/the-spa-part-of-the-existing-application` or `the-spa-part-of-the-existing-application.cshtml` in the real appliaction.

Comment: but how could it be the `/Index` of the Razor site and the `/Index` of the Blazor site at the same time?

Comment: Let's forget about `Index` then. There is no page called `Index` in Blazor application.

Comment: You can host a complete Blazor Server App in a Razor Pages page, via the component  html tag helper . See the docs how to do that.

Comment: As you know, Blazor has two flavors: WebAssembly and server-side. It seems you want to use the latter. The WASM version also has some flavors: ASP.Net core hosted, standalone and progressive web app. I'm guessing you are using the ASP.net core hosted? I don;t think you can put WASM pages in a Razor pages project...

Comment: @enet, I'm using Blazor WASM and have no plans to switch to Blazor Server.

Comment: @JHBonarius, "I don;t think you can put WASM pages in a Razor pages project", why is that? It is supposed to be a client-side technology that should not interfere with what you do on the server. In theory, I should be able to serve Blazor WASM from PHP, Node, or whatever.

Comment: Let me clarify: as soon as you copy a Razor Component from your Blazor WASM project to your Razor Pages project, it turns into a server-side application. That has to do with the project settings, specifically compiler. As Razor pages project is compiled to x86/arm binary, while a Blazor WASM project is compiled to WASM. Of course you can /host/ a compiled WASM anywhere. But if you want to combine Razor Pages and WASM, you need two separate projects (like in the default Blazor WASM ASP.net hosted template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on what you've written so far take a look at [ShaunCurtis/Blazor-Experimental on Github](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor-Experimental).  It's a temporary Repo for some experimental code.  Ignore BlazorTest.  The startup project is Blazor-Experimental.

The default page is a normal razor page.  It's a mixed Razor, Blazor Server and Blazor WASM site.  All the WASM routes look like `wasm/fetchdata`, so we have different URLs for all the Server and WASM "Pages".

Startup differentiates URLs using multiple endpoints, so any URL that is in the "scope" of the Blazor WASM application gets set to `_wasm.cshtml`.  Anything else that can't be mapped directly is in the "scope" of the Blazor Server Application at `_host.cshtml`.  All plan Razor pages on the site get served as is.  You don't need the Blazor Server bit at all, just fallback to the default Razor page.

```
  endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/wasm/{**segment}", "/_wasm");
  endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

To summarise the answer:

- Create a Blazor WASM project. You can copy the one from Blazor Hosted template.
- Reference the project from the Razor Pages project.
- Create the page that will host Blazor WASM; e.g., `Wasm.cshtml`, and make sure the page route is not set; i.e., only `@page` at the top of the page, so that it takes the default route `/wasm`.
- Copy the code from `index.html` in the Blazor WASM project into `Wasm.cshtml`.
- Important: If you are using your own layout, it is important to have `<base href="/" />` on the page or the layout `<head>` section.
- Remove all the static files from form the Blazor WASM project; e.g., `index.html`.
- Remove all `*.razor` pages from the Blazor WASM project.
- Add `Wasm.razor` to the Blazor WASM project and set its route to `/wasm`; i.e., `@page "/wasm"`.
- In `Startup.cs` in the Razor Pages project, add `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();` after `app.UseStaticFiles();`.
- Also in the same `Startup.cs`, add `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/wasm/{**segment}", "/wasm");` inside `app.UseEndpoints()` lambda.
- Now run the application and navigate to `/wasm`. You should see the content of your `Wasm.razor` in addition to whatever layout you have set. You will get the same result when you paste the URL `http://whateveryoursiteis/wasm`.

Comment: @TheBlueSky - thanks.  One of those background tinkering projects I've been working on for a while. See [Hydra - Multi SPAs on a site](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin) for my latest spin on it.  [Hydra Demo Site](https://cec-blazor-examples.azurewebsites.net/).  Anyone - feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information, so I'll have to make a number of guesses.

I guess you based your WASM integration on the Blazor WASM ASP.NET hosted template. That template consists of three projects: The `.Client` project, the `.Server` project and some extra project with shared models (they're probably doing clean architecture). The server project is a Razor pages project and the client a WASM project.

What you must understand is that a Blazor WASM project is not comparable with a Razor pages application. A Blazor WASM, or actually any WASM file is a different kind of binary and is **fully run at the client**! It is a client-side application. I.e. the output binary is totally different. You cannot have one project that generates both a server (x86/arm) binary and a client (WASM) binary. You need two separate projects.

What actually happens while compiling the WASM project, is that all page routing is also converted to WASM. Just inspect your network traffic when you change a page. Even though you browser url changes, that's *fake*... there is no network traffic! In fact, you stay on the same page.

Now think what happens when you enter "[..]/counter" manually in the browser. The host will actually again download the same `.wasm` file from the root ("/" = "/Index") and then parse the routing client-side.

Going back to your problem. For some reason you copied all the contents from the Blazer WASM project `wwwroot/index.html` to a Razor Page project `Pages/Index.cshtml`. Now you're confusing the whole routing system. When you type "[...]/counter", the WASM router will tell you that the `.wasm` file needs to be downloaded from "/Index". At the same time the Razor Pages router will tell you the compiled `Index.cshtml` is available at "/Index". That will give your *"AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: /Index /Index"*.

Just look at the Summary of `UseBlazorFrameworkFiles`:

> Configures the application to serve Blazor WebAssembly framework files from the root path "/".

Solution is just to keep the `index.html` in the WASM project as is. Just look at the default Blazor WASM ASP.Net app: it hosts Blazor WASM, Razor Pages *and* MVC at the same time and routing is just fine.

A different solution would be to use the overload of `UseBlazorFrameworkFiles`, where you can give a path prefix. E.g.

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/wasm");
```

You will need to fix other routing.

edit:
So let's give a case. you have:

- A Blazor WASM project that serves pages `/`, `/counter`, etc.
- A Razor pages project that serves pages `/weatherforecast`, etc.

Now:

1. you start the app on `/`. This loads the WASM from the server.
2. Next you click on the counter icon. *this doesn't change the page!*: it shows the counter page and updates the navigation url, but doensn't load a new page.
3. Now to go to `weatherforecast`. This is not found in the WASM, so a new page is actually loaded from the server. (either a razor page or controller/view)
4. If you would go back to `counter`, this is not found on the server, so the server 'falls-back' to the root (`/Index`) and loads the WASM again. Next is look if `counter` is found in the WASM.

Having a dynamic `/Index` will disrupt this system, so you'll have to manually solve all the routing.

Comment: To re-iterate what @JHBonarius has said, and put it a slightly different way.  Once the Blazor Application starts, no more URL navigation takes place.  Routing is really a bit of a misnomer.  Blazor Routing means taking the submitted URL, working out what new component needs loading into the CURRENT page by the `Router` component and loading it. Then sink the navigation request without trace.  Only `NavigationManager.NavigateTo ("URL", true)` will force a new page load (and destroy the current SPA instance).

Comment: @ShaunCurtis that's only true for a Blazor WASM app. Server-side is a different story.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis I just checked: the Blazor WASM part is also not fully true. It's only true for pages that can be internally routed. If you route to a page outside of the app (can be MVC, Razor Page, html, etc) it is still externally routed (using "navigation" as you refer to).

Comment: @JHBonarius, your first guess is not accurate, unless you mean I was inspired by the template. I already have a Razor Pages application that I added Blazor WASM to and did not start from Blazor WASM hosted template. I am not sure what you meant by "not comparable". Yes, I am totally aware that Razor Pages and Blazor WASM are not related and have nothing to do with each other. I am using Razor Pages application to server the binary and I am doing so because or certain requirements and because I already have this application and have no plans to use JavaScript SPA framework.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I am going to check a couple of things that you have suggested and see if any works in my case. However, bringing back `index.html` is not an option, because removing a static page is one of the reasons I am serving Blazor WASM from Razor Pages. By the way, I did some progress yesterday after posting this question and I am not getting this error now, but different one related to where Blazor WASM files are served. So, maybe something like `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/wasm");` will help.

Comment: @JHBonarius you are correct on both counts.  Re-reading what I wrote, I was patently unclear on what I said.

Comment: @TheBlueSky Like I said in the comment to your question: with "not comparable" I mean, the output binary is totally different. You cannot have one project that generates both a server (x86/arm) binary and a client (WASM) binary. You need two separate projects.

Comment: @TheBlueSky you must realize that the WASM binary needs to be loaded from root ('/Index') when you navigate to a page withing the WASM. see my update.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I think you have an incorrect assumption here. I never said I have one project. I have 2 projects, one that is compiled to Razor Pager application and the other that is compiled to Blazor WASM application. However, instead of loading Blazor WASM assbmlies from a static page, I want to load them from a `cshtml` page.

Comment: @TheBlueSky Maybe you understand why I start my answer with "You give very little information". If you want help, you should add all the necesary details. [Read the SO help topic on this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or better [the linked blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). If you don't give all the necessary details, we have to fill in the blanks ourselves and can have it wrong, wasting our and your time.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I appreciate if you ask me for the details rather than what it feels to me as if I neglected these details on purpose. "If you don't give all the necessary details, we have to fill in the blanks ourselves", I will respectfully disagree with this, because the other way to approach it is to ask for more details that you think are important. For me, I thought what I put in the question is enough, because "anyone" could follow the steps that I mentioned and reproduce the issue. I was wrong too here, but I do not think it is the end, I can modify the question and add details.